# check date if today and return whether today or normal date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap plugin as datepicker, I wrote a function to check whether it's today or not using pure js..

nothing happen, I wonder why.. the datepicker value is in format like dd/mm/yyyy

```
var datepicker = $('#datepicker').val();

        checkToday(datepicker);

        function checkToday(datepicker){
            datepickerDay =  datepicker.slice(0, datepicker.indexOf('/'));
            var d = new Date();
            var dToday = d.getDate() ;
            dToday.toString();

            if(datepickerDay == dToday){
                return "Today"
                alert('Today');
            }
            else{
                return datepicker;
                alert(datepicker);
            }
        }
```

Comment: First, Do you want to change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: nope.. if it's today then replace it with 'today', else remain the format and print it out..

Comment: var datepicker = $('#datepicker').val(); part is from jquery.Not the peo javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use **parseInt** Also you can't put anything after the return

```
var datepicker = $('#datepicker').val();


    function checkToday(datepicker) {
        datepickerDay = datepicker.slice(0, datepicker.indexOf('/'));
        var d = new Date();
        var dToday = d.getDate();
        dToday.toString();

        if (datepickerDay == dToday) {
            return "Today";

        } else {
            return datepicker;

        }
    }

    alert(checkToday(datepicker));
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8jF2/)

Comment: what a silly mistake.. i should hv run the before it declare.. thanks!!

Comment: It is not the correct code it will alert true for same date in all month like it will give true for 26/10/2013,26/09/2013 and so on. this is not the proven code...

Answer (score 0):

You van convert both the dates in dates format then compare by date, month and year.

try this

```
 function checkToday(datepicker){
        var datepickerDay =  new Date(datepicker); //creating date object from string 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        var d = new Date(); // date object

// now lets comapare date, Month and year to get correct result 
        if(d.getDate()==datepicker.getDate() && d.getMonth()==datepicker.getMonth() && d.getYear()==datepicker.getYear()){
            return "Today"
            alert('Today');
        }
        else{
            return datepicker;
            alert(datepicker);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...